# tmux over SSH: locale problem

Tags: ssh, locale

I ssh to my Raspberry Pi running Raspian from my mac and try to run tmux, but I'm getting this error:

```
tmux: need UTF-8 locale (LC_CTYPE) but have ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

As suggested elsewhere, I commented

```
#   SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

in /etc/ssh/ssh_config on my macbook and

```
#AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the Raspberry Pi. Both should prevent the Pi from getting a hickup because of the locale on the mac.

The output of locale is this:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

It has sometimes been en_GB.UTF-8 instead of POSIX, don't know why that keeps changing. In /etc/default/locale I added

```
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Exporting LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 on the command line *does* work and I guess I could put it in .bashrc, but that seems like a cheap hack for something where there should be a sound solution. I ran locale-gen and raspi-config/localization a zillion times and rebooting, without a lasting effect.

How is localization configuration done properly?

Comment: Had the same problem. This worked for me https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278401/307353 . You have to use 'sudo' to run the commands

Comment: Ok, so in /etc/locale.gen I commented #en_GB.UFT-8 and uncommented en_US.UTF-8, ran locale-gen again and voila, problem gone. What is the lesson to be learned here? Use US locales, they work?

Comment: I left both uncommented and selected GB as the default. On one Pi it actually still worked after swapping back to GB.

Comment: It is unclear from your question HOW you tried to set locale. This CAN be done manually, but requires a number of steps. `raspi-config` is the recommended method, as this generates and installs ALL the files required. The error suggests you have not correctly setup; I suggest you use a `UTF-8` locale. I use `en_AU.UTF-8 UTF-8` you should try `en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. As I said, I ran raspi-config localization more than once.

Comment: I gather from the comments that your issue is solved. Care to post (and accept) an answer yourself?

Comment: Well, I simply made the observation, that the problem disappeared, when I switch to US locales. I don’t know why, it might be coincidental. A proper answer should be given by someone with more insight on the issue.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and the suggestions didn't work for me. Generation of the locales doesn't appear to be the problem, as exporting them works without problems (that would throw errors otherwise). Setting everything by hand to en_US.UTF-8 still leaves me with POSIX after rebooting. I don't have this problem with any of my dozens of debian stretch machines. Just with raspbian stretch.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can have multiple causes. Apart from improperly configured locales and SSH env settings which have already been covered here, my particular case was solved by setting `UsePAM yes` in */etc/ssh/sshd_config*. This was the default setting, but the [Foundation Security Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/security.md) recommended changing it to `no`.